# Mercurial: Windows client for remote development

Tags: version-control, mercurial, tortoisehg

We have a test server where every developer has their own sandbox. In fact, our web project is so huge that we can't allow developers to edit everything even in sandbox. For example, there are some password files from some other web services that developers don't have permissions to see. Anyway, the thing is, we can't allow developers to clone whole projects to their own PC's for development. So we want to work remotely.

Which Windows client supports REMOTE mercurial repository exploring? I know that tortoiseHG is not capable of doing this. I tried to mount the project directory with sftpdrive software, but tortoiseHG just froze after I tried to 'explore repository' (it's probably because of low bandwidth in the office).

Please, is there any mercurial GUI client for Windows that can work over sftp?

Comment: 'Anyway the thing is we can't allow to clone whole project to own PC for development. So we want to work remotely.' Then why do you insist on using DVCS, which is not designed to work in such configuration? Also, there is really only one Windows client, TortoiseHg merely wraps around it.

Comment: "which can work over sftp" --- sftp is very slow protocol for huge amount of files. So if it is exist (but I believe there aren't any) - it will work as slow as mounted by sftpdrive directory.

Comment: what about some web application like tortoiseHG?

Comment: to  PiotrLegnica: was using SVN remotely for years with netbeans =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such client. And I don't thing it will exist ever. [List of clients](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/OtherTools).

If your web project is in fact a web multi-project with shared ressources, you can split your repository in subrepositories ([subrepo](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Subrepository)) and fine tune permission at subrepositories level.

EDIT about comments:

if the only environment where all <strike>things</strike> resources (devices, password files, ...) are only met on the server, you can't make local development on your computer. Either you refactor your code and include mocks for non-existent resources, so your developers' computer can behaves like the server, or you continue to use sandboxes on servers and you make scripts on server that pull changes from a staging repository.

Comment: any suggestions how to do remote development with mercurial? for example: there's sftp connection, I'm working on osx at home, I can't launch apache/mysql/php on my mac (there are tons of reasons for this apart resources, some devices which are connected to server and etc.. something very unique that you can't have at home) My manager want to see test version changes on some domain like test.mycompany.com . question: HOW TO MANAGE MERCURIAL REPO APART SSH??

Comment: the only solution I can think about is to have some editor which synchronizes files between sftp and local drive. then to have to repos: one is in sftp, and other one is in local drive. so just manage mercurial on local drive, and then sync this with sftp files (especially .hg folder)

Answer (score 3):

You should decompose your web app into multiple repositories and let the developers only have read/write access (via clone, push, and pull not some nonsense file xfer protocol).  Something like:

```
/webapp  (top level repository)
  |
  +---- secret stuff here
  |
  +---- more secret stuff here
  |
  +---- developer-okay-code-only-repo
```

Where /webapp is the whole system in revision control, and it has many files in it that developers can't access, and then has within in a [subrepo](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Subrepository) that the developers can clone and pull from (and maybe push-to).

Comment: ok secret stuff will not arrive into programmers pc, how he will test the application????? you'll got tons of errors because those files do not exists. btw this scenario is also about slow pc/laptops with shitty windows, where they have no brains to configure WAMP for them selfs...

Comment: They test by pushing their modified repo back to a **personal clone** on the combined server, where something like Hudson (or any continuous integration tool you like) does the build and runs their private clone on a per-user port.