# Open source web app for managing mercurial repos, or any other remote development practices with mercurial

Tags: mercurial

Is there's any web application in open source world like bitbucket?? This is all about remote development.( discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244593/mercurial-windows-client-for-remote-development) )

Some developers do not know how to use ssh ( yeah Lithuanian universities forever.. ), we have some devices which doesn't have drivers for windows or mac, we can't give every device to every developer for local development. So it's **impossible** to develop locally. On the link above, one user mentioned that mercurial is not designed for remote development. Any other practices for this?

I have only 2 solutions:

1) to find web application like bitbucket, to manage repos with all developers team

2) to find IDE which capable to synchronize sftp directory with local drive directory, and all mercurial operations would be done on local drive with local mercurial client like tortoiseHG.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out RhodeCode: https://bitbucket.org/marcinkuzminski/rhodecode/src. It has push/pull over http capabilities.

Comment: recently found gitlab, amazing stuff!!!

Answer (score 0):

On the server, use the hook in .hg/hgrc to make what your user can't.

Basic workflow for you user will be:

1. change the code
2. push the code to a staging repository with a hook to do the server part (mercurial integration exists with a lot of IDE)

   - your server can push compiled code to another computer
   - your server can do ssh (if you instruct it correctly)
   - no need to give access to webapp's servers
3. go on the website and test
4. go to step 1 until code is working
5. push the code to stable repository

Comment: it's looks like developer need to write code blindly and then push buggy code to test it??? now this process is worser then to make private "ssh basics" lessons for each developer...